# Martensitic transformation, start and finish temperatures

Tags: materials-engineering, alloys, phase-transitions

Searching about the microstructure of Cu-Ni-Zn alloys I came across this article (published 2017) which in its conclusion section says:

> "It was observed that the starting and finishing transformation
> temperatures from austenite to martensite ($A_s$, $A_f$) affected by Zn
> percent."

As far as know, the starting and finishing temperatures from austenite to martensite must be $M_s$ and $M_f$, so I'm confused now. Any ideas if it's a mistake in the article or everything is okay and I'm getting this wrong?

P.S.:

- $A_s$ - Austenite start temperature
- $A_f$ - Austenite finish temperature
- $M_s$ - martensite start temperature
- $M_f$ - martensite finish temperature

Comment: Could you link the article for context?

Comment: Of course. See the Conclusion:
https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.4975451

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a typo in the paper. As they mention in the introduction, austenite is the "hot" phase of this compound, so it should form on heating martensite. In their experiments, they heat  samples with varying compositions to determine at what temperature the austensitic transformation starts/finishes.

The martensite temperatures should refer to the transformation from austenite to martensite on cooling. So their experiment does give them the austenite temperatures, but they erroneously refer to the austenite to martensite transformation in their Experimental and Conclusion sections.